# Vuex dynamic module undefined state in mutations

Tags: state, vuex, store, nuxt.js

I'm trying to troubleshoot a Vue plugin to get it to work with Nuxt. It's using dynamic store modules, and for some reason all the mutations it's using get a `state is undefined` error.

The basics of it are:

index.js

```
import mixin from './src/mixin'
import store from './src/store'

export default {
    install: function(Vue, options = {}) {
        options = {
            store: null,
            ...options
        }

        options.store.registerModule('shopify', store)

        // define mixin
        Vue.mixin(mixin)
    }
}
```

And then the store.js file is basically this:

```
export default {
    state: {
        product: [],
    },
    mutations: {
        UPDATE_CACHED_RESULT(state, { id, data }) {
            // This is the line that throws a state error
            state.product[id] = data
        }
    },
    actions: {
    }
}
```

I'm assuming I have the syntax wrong now that this in in a Nuxt setup, but I'm drawing a blank.

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should access your `store` through `context` property. As stated in Nuxt.js documentation, if you export function, then [`context`](https://nuxtjs.org/api/context#the-context) will be provided as the first argument of that function. So you can get access to the actual `store` of your app, and aplly some changes to the store (in your case register module).

```
export default (context, inject) => {
  context.store.registerModule("foo", {
    state: {
      id: 1
    },
    mutations: {
      bar(state) {
        state.id = 2;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

And then register that plugin in `nuxt.config.js`:

```
plugins: [
  "~/plugins/name-of-your-plugin"
]
```

P.S.: This module registration worked well in my application, but I am not sure about `mixin`, maybe adding these lines of code could help:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import mixin from "./src/mixin";

Vue.mixin(mixin);

// then export aforementioned function.
```

[Reference](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins#inject-into-context).

Comment: Hi, Im having a similar issue my problem is that `install` within my custom plugin is only called once. Therefore, the module is registered and then on subsequent loads the module does not exist